# On Mac after downgrading node version from 0.10 to 0.8 npm is not working

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

After downgrading node version from 0.10 to 0.8 npm is not working, I have tried npm -v

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:6
let url
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
```

Comment: I am new to mac and facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to remove the node completely and install the new vesion. I have followed following setps to uninstall the node and reinstall it.

[How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x?rq=1)